# MySQL max group by return wrong values

Tags: mysql

```
Mysql max not working, only max id getting but group by is not working
```

only showing min values

```
CREATE TABLE `feedbacklogs` (
  `fid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `remarks` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4081 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

select status,max(fid) from feedbacklogs group by eid
```

I Getting wrong values

```
SELECT eid,remarks,max(fid) FROM feedbacklogs
group by eid
```

Please give me solution

Sample Data

```
fid - 01 , status - active, eid-70
fid - 02 , status - deleted, eid-72
fid - 03 , status - deleted, eid-70
```

actual result : fid - 03 , status - deleted, eid-70

i get : fid - 03 , status - active, eid-70

Comment: How can you have two columns with the same name?

Comment: Show sample data , expected result and result you get.

Comment: in your create you missed  fid  ... update your question add  a proper data sample you actual result and your expected  result

Comment: update help me thanks

Comment: **SELECT eid,remarks,max(fid) FROM feedbacklogs
group by eid,remarks** that would be ok, but remarks is not in your table create

Comment: So review your question and your column names

Comment: now corrected my question

Answer (score 1):

When the column in group by don't match the column without aggregation function in  SELECT the value for these colums is unpredictable

*(this happen with mysql version < 5.7  for mysql >= 5.7 this use of group by, by default, raise an error)*

```
SELECT eid,remarks,max(fid) FROM feedbacklogs
group by eid
```

you should use

```
SELECT eid,remarks,max(fid) FROM feedbacklogs
group by eid, remarks
```

or

```
 SELECT eid,min(remarks),max(fid) FROM feedbacklogs
group by eid
```

or  if you want the remark for the max_fid

```
SELECT eid,remarks, max_fid 
from  feedbacklogs  f 
inner join  (
    SELECT eid, max(fid) max_fid 
    FROM feedbacklogs
    group by eid

) t on t.eid = f.eid and t.max_fid = f.fid
```